# I have a problem with my R shiny dashboard i dont know what could be the problem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gbm)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="Basic Dashboard",
                    dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                                 messageItem(
                                     from = "Personal Doctor",
                                     message = "Please schedule an Appointment if there is any issue"
                                 ),
                                 messageItem(
                                     from = "New User",
                                     message = "How do I use the Dashboard?",
                                     icon = icon("question"),
                                     time = "13:45"
                                 ),
                                 messageItem(
                                     from = "Support",
                                     message = "The new server is ready.",
                                     icon = icon("life-ring"),
                                     time = "2020-05-13"
                                 )
                    ),
                    dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                                 notificationItem(
                                     text = "7 new users today",
                                     icon("users")
                                 ),
                                 notificationItem(
                                     text = "5 Doctors are available ",
                                     icon("hospital"),
                                     status = "success"
                                 ),
                                 notificationItem(
                                     text = "Server load at 97%",
                                     icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                     status = "warning"
                                 )
                    ),
                    dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                                 taskItem(value = 90, color = "green",
                                          "Heart Disease"
                                 )
                    )),

    #Sidebar Content
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Heart Disease",tabName = "Heart Disease",icon=icon("dashboard"))
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            valueBoxOutput("age"),
            valueBoxOutput("gender"),
            valueBoxOutput("BMI")

        ),

        box(
            title="Your Probability of Having Heart Disease is:",
            textOutput("Pred")
        ),

            box(
                title = "Please Fill in the Following to Get the Likelihood of Having Heart Disease",status="danger",background="navy", solidHeader = TRUE,
                numericInput(inputId='age', 
                             label='1.Please Enter your Age:', 
                             value=NA,min = NA, 
                             max = NA, step = NA,
                             width = NULL),
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId='sex', 
                                   label='Please check your gender:', 
                                   c('female','male'), 
                                   selected = NULL, 
                                   inline = FALSE,width = NULL),
                numericInput(inputId='weight', 
                             label='1.Please Enter your Weight:', 
                             value =NA ,min = NA, 
                             max = NA, step = NA,
                             width = NULL),
                numericInput(inputId='height', 
                             label='1.Please Enter your Height:', 
                             value =NA ,min = NA, 
                             max = NA, step = NA,
                             width = NULL),
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'cp',label='Please describe the type of chest pain you have experienced:',
                                   c('normal pains','extreme pain','no pains','asymptomatic pain'),
                                   selected=NULL,
                                   inline = FALSE,width=NULL),
                numericInput('trestbps',label='Please Enter your resting blood pressure in mm/Hg:',
                             min=50,
                             max=200,
                             value = 120),
                numericInput(inputId = 'chol',label='Please enter your cholestrol levels:',
                             value=203,
                             min=80,
                             max=NA,
                             step=NA,
                             width=NULL),
            ),
            box(
                title = "Please Fill in the Following to Get the Likelihood of Having Heart Disease",status="danger",background="navy", solidHeader = TRUE,
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'fbs',label='How can you describe your blood sugar levels after fasting:',
                                   c('normal','abnormal'),selected=NULL,
                                   inline=FALSE,width=NULL),

                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'restecg',label='How is your breathing when you are resting?',
                                   c('normal','probable difficulties','difficult'),
                                   selected=NULL,
                                   inline=FALSE,width=NULL),
                numericInput(inputId = 'thalach',label='what is the maximum heart rate you can achieve?',
                             value=100,
                             min=71,
                             max=NA,
                             step=NA,
                             width=NULL),
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'exang',label='Have you experienced any chest pains after exercising?',
                                   c('no','yes'),selected=NULL,
                                   inline = FALSE,
                                   width = NULL),
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'ca',label='Have you had any blood circulation problems?',
                                   c('all the time','a few times','quite a few times','almost never','never'),selected=NULL,
                                   inline=FALSE,
                                   width=NULL),
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'thal',label = 'How can you describe the nature of your blood?',
                                   c('has unknown defect','is normal','has fixed defects','has reversible defects'),
                                   selected=NULL,
                                   inline = FALSE,
                                   width=NULL)
            )
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) { 
    output$age <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            paste0(input$age), "Age", icon = icon("thumbs-up"),
            color = "light-blue"
        )
    })

    output$gender <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            paste0(input$sex),"Gender",icon = icon("list"),
            color = "aqua"
        )
    })

    output$BMI <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            paste0(input$weight/(input$height^2)), "Body Mass Index(BMI)", icon = icon("ambulance"),
            color = "blue"
        )
    })
    model<-readRDS("F:/Project Machine learning/Saved Models/model_gbm.RDS")
    data<-reactive({
        req(input$sex)
        req(input$cp)
        req(input$fbs)
        req(input$restecg)
        req(input$exang)
        req(input$ca)
        req(input$thal)
        req(input$age)
        req(input$trestbps)
        req(input$chol)
        req(input$thalach)

       df_final= data.frame(
                            age=input$age,
                            sex=input$sex,
                            cp=input$cp,
                            trestbps=input$trestbps,
                            chol=input$chol,
                            fbs=input$fbs,
                            restecg=input$restecg,
                            thalach=input$thalach,
                            exang=input$exang,
                            ca=input$ca,
                            thal=input$thal)
        })

    pred=reactive({predict(model,data(),type="response")})

    output$Pred <- renderPrint(pred())



    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It keeps on bringing the error of;

> Warning: Error in predict.train: type must be either "raw" or "prob"
>     119: stop
>     118: predict.train
>     116:  [F:\Project Machine learning\kristophe/app.R#190]
>     100: pred
>      99: renderPrint
>      98: func
>      82: origRenderFunc
>      81: output$Pred
>       1: shiny::runApp

Dont know what the problem could be.

Comment: Hi, when you ask a question on StackOverflow, you have to provide a minimal and reproducible example. Here, your example is not minimal because there are plenty of things in the `ui` that seem useless for your problem, and your example is not reproducible because you use data that only you have access to (the RDS file). Therefore, you should modify your example to stick to these criteria. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details

Comment: +1 for @bretauv's comment.  99% of what you show is irrelevant to your problem.  But, even though I know nothing about the caret package, I think you have all the information you need in the error message.  It tells you that `type` must take either the value `"raw"` or the value `"prob"`.  You specify `type="response"` in the third line up from the end of the code you provide.